# Usage of globals in Python

Tags: python, global-variables

So I have a lot of globals in my code shared by different methods.

Is there a better way for the methods to know it is a global than me writing global in front of every global variable?

Comment: Use fewer globals? You only need to mark a local as global if you assign to it, in any case.

Comment: If you are simply _using_ the values, you don't need to declare them as variables if you don't have clashing names within the same method

Comment: I like creating a dictionary I call `env` which holds "globals", but I don't change these often after init

Comment: I don't have clashing names but it still gives me an error when I try to use it, like they are not declared. Thanks.

Comment: @AssafMalki If it is complaining, try to create minimal example, presenting the problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Also global variables in Python actually have module(file) scope. So you can't use them in other modules if you don't import.

Answer (score 0):

There is no better way *for a variable to "know" it is global*. There is, however, a better way to structure your program to avoid needing to use globals. Though, don't think of using `global` as telling the computer it's global -- even though you must if you are modifying it -- think of it as expressing your *intent*, which helps serve as documentation for your code. If variables just magically worked as globals, how would you or anyone else know if that was what you wanted, or it was a bug in your code? Declaring a variable explicitly as global adds clarity.

That being said, if you are only accessing (versus modifying) the variables, you don't have to declare them as global. Python will automatically look in the list of globals if it doesn't find a local variable with a given name. It's important to know that in python, "global" refers to the module. Python doesn't have truly global variables.

You should learn how to write your code using classes, and then use instance variables where you would otherwise use globals. Tjis aboids the problem altogether and makes your code easier to manage and maintain over time.